# ga:itemQuantity in ga_sessions_YYYMMDD (Big Query)

Tags: google-analytics, metrics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to replicate the GA Quantity metric (ga:itemQuantity) using standardSQL and querying the GA export to BigQuery date partitioned tables (ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD).

I have tried the following, but 'quantity' is always null:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
sum(hit.item.itemQuantity) as quantity
FROM `precise-armor-133520.1500218.ga_sessions_20170801` t
CROSS JOIN
UNNEST(t.hits) AS hit
order by 1 ASC;
```

Other metrics work and match 100% with the GA UI so I am assuming it's not a data export problem.  For example:

```
SELECT 
sum( totals.totalTransactionRevenue ) as revenue, sum( totals.transactions ) as transactions
FROM `precise-armor-133520.1500218.ga_sessions_201708*` t
CROSS JOIN
UNNEST(t.hits) AS hit
group by `date`
order by `date` asc
```

These totals match Revenue and Transactions (metrics) in GA UI respectively.

What is the standardSQL query for the GA metric quantity (ga:itemQuantity)?

Comment: I wonder if `hits.product.productQuantity` works?

Comment: I did try that as well and ended with at least a returned value with the query below, however it does not match the metric "Quantity" in the GA web UI.   SELECT sum(p.productQuantity),d
  from (SELECT h.product, `date` as d
          FROM  `precise-armor-133520.1500218.ga_sessions_201710*` 
          , UNNEST(hits) as h
       ), UNNEST(product) as p
group by d
order by d asc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to match "Quantity" in GA's web UI by each date, use the following standard SQL:

```
SELECT
   SUM(product.productQuantity)
   ,`date`
FROM
  `precise-armor-133520.1500218.ga_sessions_*`
  ,UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  ,UNNEST(hits.product) AS product
WHERE hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6"
and _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20170801' and FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE)
group by 2
order by 2 asc
```

Comment: Do you have  any clue about what is the field item quantity in Big Query? I've lost hours trying to ffigure out before coming here and find this life-saving question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
sku,
SUM(qtd) qtd
FROM(
SELECT
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT productSKU sku, productQuantity qtd FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(product) WHERE ecommerceAction.action_type = '6') data
  FROM `precise-armor-133520.1500218.ga_sessions_20170801`
),
UNNEST(data)
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY qtd DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Not sure how you managed to `unnest` the product fields, maybe this solves your issue.